# galilean transformation identity

Tags: linear-transformations, differential-operators

in an excericse im doing the gallilean transformation in 3D of spacetime is defined as
$$
\vec{x}=\vec{x}'+\vec{v}t
$$
and
$$
t=t'
$$
and later it says that
$
\vec{\nabla}=\vec{\nabla}'
$
.That I still understand. But after that he writes
$$
\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{dt'}{dt}\frac{d}{dt'}+\frac{d\vec{x}'}{dt}\vec{\nabla}'
$$
that I dont get. Im assuming that $\frac{d\vec{x}'}{dt}\vec{\nabla}'=0$ since $\frac{dt'}{dt}\frac{d}{dt'}=\frac{d}{dt}$. But I dont know why that should be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{x}'$ is a function of $t$ (or equivalently $t'$) then, by the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dt'}f(t',\vec{x}')=\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}f(t',\vec{x}')+\vec{\nabla}'f(\vec{x}')\cdot\frac{d\vec{x}'}{dt'}.
$$
In short,
$$
\boxed{\frac{d}{dt'}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}+\frac{d\vec{x}'}{dt'}\cdot\vec{\nabla}'\,.}
$$
To me it looks like that, the term
$$
\frac{dt'}{dt}\frac{d}{dt'}
$$
is a bad notation for $\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\,.$ In this setting one should more carefully distinguish between partial and total time derivatives.